# CSS overflow not working

Tags: css, overflow

I don't see why a simple overflow in a div doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<style type="text/css">
.ename {width:400px;overflow:hidden;padding:0 5px 0 5px;color:#EE3129;line-height:25px;text-transform:uppercase;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ename"> qksdjlqjsdkqsd qksdjlkqsjdklqsjd qsdkjqslkdjkqsjdklqsjd sdkqsjdkqsjdkqjsdkqd qdlkjqsdkjqskdjkqlsjdkqs qsdkjqskdj </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Actually, it is showing the expected behaviour. What do you expect it to happen? How should it be for you? Just `doesn't work` won't give the expected stuff.

Comment: You should give it a height property so the text wouldn't try to fit itself within the given width, giving respect to the given height of the cotnainer.

Comment: @AlainZelink: If you see, most of the answers are conveying to use the `white-space: nowrap;` CSS property.

Answer (score 4):

Text will always wrap before it overflows. Your page is behaving as expected. If you want it to always stick to one line, you'll want `white-space: nowrap`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tc2wA/

Answer (score 2):

set `height` what ever you want

```
.ename {width:400px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0 5px 0 5px;
color:#EE3129;
line-height:25px;
text-transform:uppercase;
height: 58px;}
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNTWK/)

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `white-space: nowrap;` CSS

If you want to make the text in a single line and it shouldn't go out, you need to use `white-space: nowrap;` CSS.

#### Code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<style type="text/css">
  .ename {width:400px;overflow:hidden;padding:0 5px 0 5px;color:#EE3129;line-height:25px;text-transform:uppercase; white-space: nowrap;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ename"> qksdjlqjsdkqsd qksdjlkqsjdklqsjd qsdkjqslkdjkqsjdklqsjd sdkqsjdkqsjdkqjsdkqd qdlkjqsdkjqskdjkqlsjdkqs qsdkjqskdj </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And that shows your output this way:

[image: Nowrap]

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/ocacuw/1

Answer (score 0):

The text in the `div` is not overflowing because it can simply wrap and expand the `div`s height.
If you add `white-space: nowrap;` to the css, you will see that the text overflows.

Or, if you want the text to wrap to some extent, just add `height: 20px;` or any height value to the style.